# Firebird "key size exceed implementation restriction for index" error message if the index is created during active work?

Tags: indexing, firebird, firebird1.5

I have Firebird database and I have created index on the varchar(30) field during active working name (I managed to complete and commit the `create index` statement, somtimes commit is not possible during working time, i.e., when there are other connections besides the active SYSDBA connection to the database) and after it I have started to receive error messages:

```
Implementation limit exceeded key size exceed implementation restriction for index INDEX_NAME
```

I can not reproduce such error message on my local databases for whom I have only one (SYSDBA) or only few non-SYSDBA connections. Is it possible that this limit exception is due to efforts to create index during active workload?

Of course, I am aware of http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/25723 and http://www.firebirdfaq.org/ip_ib_indexcalculator.htm but non-Unicode varchar(30) is definitely small enough to have its own index and table has only 3 other integer or date indices, so - the implementation limit could not have been reached.

Well, I am using Firebird 1.5 (it is deprecated already 10 years), but I guess that other versions can have such behavior as well.

Comment: Things changed with Firebird 2.0, with that version the maximum index key size increased from max 252 bytes to 1/4 of the database page size. Without a reproducible case or at minimum the necessary DDL and specifically the character set and collation of the columns involved in the index, it is hard to come to any conclusion to the actual problem, and with Firebird 1.5 being obsolete for years, it is really time to upgrade. However things that can contribute to inflating index sizes: UNICODE_FSS (or UTF8) (character count x 3 (or x4)), and some collations may result in larger space consumption.

Comment: As an aside, that link to embarcadero.com is about InterBase and not about Firebird. Although they share a common heritage, they shouldn't be considered the same database system.